# How to divide a raster into n tiles and apply regression with terra package in r?

Tags: r, filter, terra

I have two rasters: temperature and elevation. My objective is to divide the temperature raster into 'n' non-overlapping tiles [using no of row and columns] and perform a linear regression, using elevation as the predictor 'x' and temperature as the response 'y', to correct the temperature values. Additionally, I intend to apply a high-pass filter to the output of the linear regression. Finally, I aim to merge all the tiles to obtain a single output raster. I would like to know if there is a way to accomplish this using the 'terra' package in R.

I could do the regression between two rasters but could not do tiling and apply regression and high pass filter.I am looking for reproducible codes.

Comment: Why not use {terra}'s tailored spatial functions, e.g. focal regression: https://rspatial.github.io/terra/reference/focalReg.html (overview: https://rspatial.github.io/terra/reference/terra-package.html#v-situation-spatial-context-based-methods-1)